# Escaping newline character when writing to stdout in C++

Tags: c++, escaping, newline, stdout

I have a string in my program containing a newline character:

```
char const *str = "Hello\nWorld";
```

Normally when printing such a string to stdout the \n creates a new line, so the output is:

```
Hello
World
```

But I would like to print the string to stdout with the newline character escaped, so the output looks like:

```
Hello\nWorld
```

How can I do this without modifying the string literal?

Comment: Consider providing a [mre] to demonstrate the context. Include a use of the string which demonstrates that you cannot alter the string itself and a use of the string where you want the escaping to happen.

Comment: "*How can I do this without modifying the string literal?*" - parse the string literal and output it in smaller pieces with escaped characters in between them. For instance, loop through the string, printing any character as-is that is not `'\n'`, and print any `'\n'` character as `"\\n"` instead. Alternatively, copy the string literal to a `std::string`, then replace all `'\n'` characters with `"\\n"` substring, then print out the `std::string`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you! This is the answer I was looking for - seems so obvious but it didn't cross my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I opted for (thanks [@RemyLebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau)) is to create a copy of the string and escape the desired escape sequences (`"\n"` becomes `"\\n"`).

Here is the function which does this escaping:

```cpp
void escape_escape_sequences(std::string &str) {
  std::pair<char, char> const sequences[] {
    { '\a', 'a' },
    { '\b', 'b' },
    { '\f', 'f' },
    { '\n', 'n' },
    { '\r', 'r' },
    { '\t', 't' },
    { '\v', 'v' },
  };

  for (size_t i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
    char *const c = str.data() + i;

    for (auto const seq : sequences) {
      if (*c == seq.first) {
        *c = seq.second;
        str.insert(i, "\\");
        ++i; // to account for inserted "\\"
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to be more thorough, there is also `'\a'`, `'\b'`, `'\v'`, etc. See [escape sequences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape)